# Why am I getting a type mismatch on this MyCell range error?

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a runtime error on this line:

```
                        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & SM.Range("C5").Value & ".pdf", _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Sub Statement_Autoprint()

```
        Dim MCST As Workbook: Set MCST = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim User As String: User = Environ$("Username")
        Dim SavePath As String: SavePath = "M:\comp_statements\"
        Dim CS As Worksheet: Set CS = MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet")

        Dim MgrPath As String, MyCell As Range, Printed As Integer, i As Integer, SM As Worksheet
        Printed = 0


    Call Disable

For i = 2 To CS.Range("B" & CS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If CS.Range("A" & i) <> "" & CS.Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
        Set SM = MCST.Sheets(CStr(CS.Range("A" & i)))
        SM.Calculate
        SM.Range("P1") = Format(CS.Range("B" & i), "000000000")

            For Each MyCell In SM.Range("N2:N70")
                If MyCell = "HIDE" Then
                    MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ElseIf MyCell <> "HIDE" Then
                    MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next MyCell

        If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
            DoEvents
        End If

                MgrPath = "M:\Pittsburgh\GRP4\HR_PCorpComp\2018 Midyear\Reporting\Parsley\comp_statements\" & SM.Range("K5") & "\"


                If Dir(MgrPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
                    MkDir MgrPath
                End If

                        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & SM.Range("C5").Value & ".pdf", _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False

                    Printed = Printed + 1
                End If
            Next i

            CS.Activate

            Call Re_Enable


End Sub
```

I do not have any files that exist/are open under that name, I have no clue what could be preventing this from saving. All of the other bits of code do what they're supposed to, it just can't loop to the next employee because the save is being suppressed because of that error.

Comment: Have you tried using `If MyCell.Value = "HIDE" Then` ?

Comment: Also, declare i as Long, not as Integer. There are more rows in a sheet that Integer can handle.

Comment: Or you may need to change the `in SM.Range("N2:N70")` to `in SM.Range("N2:N70").Cells`

Comment: @Mistella Still getting the error, but good point outs

Comment: In Immediate window, check what is the address of the cell. Then go to that cell in the worksheet and check if there are any formula errors or not?

Comment: Place a breakpoint (F9) on the line that throws the error, then inspect the value of the cell you're looking at. If that value is a *cell error* value, that's why you're getting a type mismatch. Error values are of type `Error`, which can only be coerced into a `Variant`. Or do what @SiddharthRout suggests, but I'd warmly recommend gettting acquainted with the debugger tools in the VBE.

Comment: Protip: `foo.Range("something")` is a hidden default member call, which makes your code implicit. Don't do `.Range("something")` when you mean `.Range("something").Value` ...and there's no need to post the same comment 3 times...

Comment: adding `.Cells` to `SM.Range("N2:N70")` in `For Each MyCell In SM.Range("N2:N70")` should not make a difference to the `Type Mismatch` error. Also check what is the value of `SM.Range("C5")` for the  runtime error.

Comment: @SiddharthRout the value in C5 of that sheet is the name of the employee, nothing looks off about it. I have no idea why an errors happening, the saved file isn't open nor does it exist yet.

Comment: Can you update your question with the save code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout question updated

Comment: I do nto see anything wrong. Can you step through the code and check what is the value of `MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & SM.Range("C5").Value & ".pdf"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I see what the problem is. The Mgr path is looking for a manager folder based on what's in the manager path: 

`MgrPath = "M:\comp_statements\" & SM.Range("K5") & "\"`

How would I go about making sure the script makes a folder based on that employee's manager based on whatever value is in K5?

Comment: @SiddharthRout something like `IF mgrpath <> exist, create a folder based on SM.Range("K5").Value` and then proceed to save the file there

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just noticed that, but it's not actually creating any folders there

Comment: Replace `<>` to `=` in your code. try this `If Dir(MgrPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it worked!!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad it is sorted.. Off to bed.. Gnite :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
For Each mycell In SM.Range("N2:N70")
    If IsError(mycell) Then
        Debug.Print mycell.Address
    Else
        mycell.EntireRow.Hidden = (mycell = "HIDE")
    End If
Next mycell
```

1. Either handle the error using `IsError` or
2. Go to the cell which the above code points to and check if there are any formula errors.

You usually get that error if the cell has formula errors.